# Не создается автоматически файл разметки activity_main в Android Studio

Tags: android

при создании проекта New Project > Empty Activity не добавляется res/values  activity_main.xml
В чем моя ошибка? Андроид Студио последней версии, язык Kotlin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте создавать не Empty Activity, а Empty Views Activity

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!

Comment: @veLmaX тогда отметьте как ответ, пожалуйста) буду очень благодарен

Comment: отметил, я на форуме первый раз поэтому многого не знаю, огромнейшее спасибо за помощь) Хорошего дня

Comment: @veLmaX взаимно!